# how can we get exact key match of object array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the exact key match of object array in angularjs instead of that I am getting all matching results. How can i achieve that?

here is the controller code:-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ToddlerCtrl', function ($scope,$filter) {


 $scope.toddlers = [
{
  "name": "Toddler One",
  "tid": "85",

},
{
  "name": "Toddler Two",
  "tid": "485",

},
{
  "name": "Toddler Three",
  "tid": "4485",

} ,
{
  "name": "Toddler Four",
  "tid": "8845",

}
];

  var found = $filter('filter')($scope.toddlers, 85  );
    console.log(found); // I want the exact match i.e. ("Toddler one" with "85" only) but I am getting 3 results.



});
```

[here is the Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8aVWchsfpMZWc769W26o?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is quite easy: Add a true as a third param to indicate that the search needs be exact. Note that 85 won´t match anything though, you need to put '85':

```
var found = $filter('filter')($scope.toddlers, '85' , true);
```

For more info check the comparator parameter in docs: [Angular Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)